# What is the best way to customize the ordering experience of the end user in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-experience, spree

I'm in the process of launching a spree app, and as part of the design requirements, I need to have a wizard which asks for information, then places an order to a product.

Imho there are two ways of doing this:

1. Trigger the wizard as part of the checkout process, if a product requires a wizard
2. Just have a wizard process on the gui which places an order (and guides through the checkout)

Option 1 would require an extension to the product model, and would be highly customized version of spree. But this will in the end support more products. So we could say if the product requires information from the user, take them through the wizard.

The second option is much simpler, but less flexible. I'd have to make sure there was no way of adding the product other than going through the wizard, which is possible...

Is there a right way of going about this? I've read that the spree checkout process is highly customizable so maybe I should concerntrate on method 1?

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree uses [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), which is essentially a state machine tool to define your own steps through checkout with various before / after / processing filters.

Two thoughts:

- Is there any reason you wouldn't introduce the wizard before the user gets to checkout? Meaning, you could define your own state machine process for adding an item to the cart to force the user to go through the wizard. The line item could then point to the extra stored data. Then the cart itself would remain uncustomized.
- Optionally, you could alter Spree's existing state_machine behavior to fit your wizard needs. Read more about Spree state machine customization [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/checkout.html#checkout-customization).

It's hard for me to say which approach would be better here, since I don't have a full understanding of what happens in the wizard. I would probably go for the first option if at all possible, because hacking at Spree's state machine process can get a little messy / tricky.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! The wizard can go before the checkout so I'll look into this. Much appreciated!